# Searching for SKU not showing results, Magento 2 EE

Tags: magento2, search

Searching with the SKU doesn't return any results.  Example of SKU:

ZOR_ZONU3103

I've made sure that the sku attribute is set as Searchable.  I have reindexed.  I tried SOLR.

Is this a known issue, or something can be adjusted to work somewhere?

Comment: I solved this with by upgrading to 2.1 and installing ElasticSearch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this with by upgrading to 2.1 and installing ElasticSearch.  I did find some SKU searches were returning results, but not all.  Elastic solved all the issues.